# ELI5: Wireless iAP

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently playing around with the pybluez package.  I am able to see a list of services offered.  One of the services offered by my iPhone 7s is something called "Wireless iAP" and "Wireless iAP v2".  What is this? Google doesn't have a clear answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the iPod Accessory Protocol (iAP) for controlling certain iPod features. See point 8 in this document for further information: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf